# R function to count duplicates of two variables in data frame

Tags: r, count, duplicates

I have a data frame like this:

| Gender | Income | Years_Edu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| m | 3428 | 5 |
| f | 8976 | 6 |
| m | 2000 | 2 |
| m | 3428 | 5 |
| f | 8976 | 6 |
| . | .... | .. |

I would like to create a new table with only unquie tuples for all three variable with an additional column for the number of duplicates.

| Gender | Income | Years_Edu | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m | 3428 | 5 | 2 |
| f | 8976 | 6 | 2 |
| m | 2000 | 2 | 1 |
| . | .... | .. | .. |

Does somebody have a tip to achieve this?

Thanks for your help and please let me know, if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this not very fancy (but functional) solution:

```
Gender<-c("m","f","m","m","f")
Income<-c(3428,8976,2000,3428,8976)
Years_Edu<-c(5,6,2,5,6)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Gender,Income,Years_Edu))

df$combo<-paste0(df$Gender,df$Income,df$Years_Edu)

df %>% group_by(combo) %>% summarise(n=n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by()` and `summarize()` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
Gender <- c("m","f","m","m","f")
Income <- c(3428,8976,2000,3428,8976)
Years_Edu <- c(5,6,2,5,6)
your_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Gender,Income,Years_Edu))
your_data %>%
  group_by(Gender, Income, Years_Edu) %>%
  summarize(Count = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Gender, Income [3]
  Gender Income Years_Edu Count
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <int>
1 f      8976   6             2
2 m      2000   2             1
3 m      3428   5             2
```

Comment: You got two "Bens" to answer your question the same way!  Wow.

Comment: @Ben - Within a minute of each other!

Comment: And we're both from the eastern part of the USA.  Geez, what's the likelihood? :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Julian - if either of our answers were helpful, consider upvoting them, and accept the one that best solves your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the necessary reputation. But both your answers were helpful